# SSL doesn't work on certain pages - what is wrong?

Tags: ssl

I just added an SSL certificate to my Wordpress website using this code (.htaccess):

```
# REDIRECT HTTP TO HTTPS RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However, when I type monersi.pl/something in browser, the certificate doesn't work, but when I type monersi.pl, everything is okay. (monersi.pl is my website)

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If it's all in one line, it will be commented out at `# Redirect HTTP...` as the `#` character is used for commenting in .htacces.

Try:

```
# REDIRECT HTTP TO HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work :( Please check again - the code is now live.

Comment: It's password protected :/

Comment: I mean, you can go to monersi.pl and it will work as it should. But if you try to visit any other page, for example monersi.pl/tatatatatata you will see that the SSL doesn't work - even if the website is password protected :/

Comment: Have you gone through your settings and made sure everything is set to `https://`, specifically `General Settings -> Wordpress Address (URL)` and `General Settings -> Site Address (URL)`?

Comment: Yes, everything is set to https :/

Comment: Can you copy and paste your .htaccess again?